# how to attach android chrome by puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

Here is an android chrome in my phone, I can find the android chrome in my pc chrome://inspect. When I click inspect, I can control the android chrome.
Now I want to control  android chrome by puppteer, how can I do it.

I try ask chatgpt. Following is the answer:
On your PC, open Chrome and go to chrome://inspect. Under the "Devices" section, you should see your Android device listed. Click on the "Inspect" link next to your device. This will open the DevTools window for your Android Chrome. In the DevTools window, you will find the Remote Debugging URL at the top. It should look something like ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/<device_id>.

However, I did not find ws://localhost:9222....

Comment: maybe https://gist.github.com/yuriteixeira/f2d9e330d7c77021189909770a31eac4 helps you